# I am trying to use an HTML form to append the results to a Text file using php

Tags: php, html

Here is my HTML form

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>HTMl FORM</h1>

    <p>
      <form action="example.php" method="POST">
        <p>Your First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
        <p>Your Last name : <input type="text" name="lname" /></p>

        <p><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="Reset”/></p>
      </form>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP file "example.php" Shows the Client what was inputted and should append to the text file "phpfile.txt"

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
 Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']); ?>.<br>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']); ?>
    </p>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname']."
        ";
        $lname = $_POST['lname']."
        ";
        $file=fopen("phpfile.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $fname);
        fwrite($file, $lname);
        fclose($file);
        }
        ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the php file to print for the user but it is not appending to the .txt file. I am unsure where I am going wrong

Comment: Have you checked what's inside `_POST`? Why you first encode `fname` and `lname` _and_ only then check if there is form submitted? Have you tried `file_put_contents`? Use `PHP_EOL` constant  or `"\r\n"` instead of new line

Comment: @Justinas I feel I am checking what is inside _POST by having it print to the user what has been inputted through the echo. I have tried 
    $txt= $_POST['fname'].' - '.$_POST['lname'] . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents('phpfile.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
which also is also not working.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you need to check whether $_POST['fname'] and $_POST['lname'] is set, as well as $_POST['Submit'], otherwise it would spit out an error because PHP sucks like that.

Comment: @ethry I added "<?php
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
?>" And it is coming back as being set.

Comment: @Elcucuy Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score -1):

You are probably getting a syntax error.
You also need to use \n to add a new line. You also need to place the echo $_POST parts in the isset function.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>HTMl FORM</h1>
    <p>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <p>Your First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
            <p>Your Last name : <input type="text" name="lname" /></p>

            <p><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
            <input type="Reset"/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </p>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        echo 'Hi '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']); 
        echo '<br>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
        $fname = $_POST['fname']."";
        $lname = $_POST['lname']."";
        $file=fopen("phpfile.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $fname." ".$lname. "\n");
        fclose($file);
    }
    ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please also add some text to your answer stating what you have done to answer the question. You can't help people by just sending the answer like that. This answer also does not answer the question.